# import javascript

Tags: javascript

Ando tratando de importar un una función que me imprime html en mi index, esto sucede al dar click en un botón y este dependiendo del valor de un select me llama a una determinada función, sin embargo al probarlo en consola me indica ( Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' ), ya he validado la sitacxys del import, pero aun si me sigue saliendo este error , no se en que este fallando. Agardezco cualquier señal que me sirva para corregir esto.

**script del botón**

```
    <script type="module" >
        $(Ini_reg).click(function(){
            let TVariedad = document.getElementById('idTFlor');
    
            // console.log(TVariedad.selectedIndex);
            // console.log(TVariedad.options[TVariedad.selectedIndex].value)
            switch (TVariedad.options[TVariedad.selectedIndex].value) {
                case 'CL':
                     console.log('clavel seleccionado');
                     import{imprimirCalidad} from './js/ECclavel.js';
                     const parte1 = imprimir(imprimirCalidad);
                    break;
                case 'MN':
                    console.log('Mini seleccionado');
                    break;                    
                case 'GB':
                    console.log('greenball seleccionado');
                    break;            
                default:
                    console.log('Valor vacío');
                    break;
            }
        });
</script>
```

**mi js externo**

```
const CalC = [
    "Abierto",
    "Corto",
    "Debil",
    "Decolorado",
    "Deformado",
    "Petalo quemado",
    "Rajado",
    "Torcido",
    "Toxicidad"
]

    export const imprimirCalidad =  (CalC) => {
        let html1='';
        CalC.forEach(item1 =>{
            html1 += `
            <input id="${item1}" type="number" placeholder="${item1}">
            `;
        });
            const inputCalidad = document.querySelector('#Calidad');
            inputCalidad.innerHTML= html1;
    };
    
    return imprimirCalidad(CalC);
```

Comment: creo que es el por el `return`. El `return` solo tiene sentido en una función que devuelve algo. Y tu lo estas usando fuera de una función, encima tu función `imprimirCalidad` no devuelve nada. Debe ser así `imprimirCalidad(CalC)`

Comment: No sólo tienes el problema de que tu módulo *externo* tiene un error, sino que la cláusula *import* debe ser la primera línea de código de tu *script*, no la puedes colocar donde se te ocurra, tal como lo tienes ahora.